# How to find out which attribute to use in this terraform code?

Tags: terraform

When I run `terraform plan`, I got this error:

> Error: Error loading /Users/antkong/infrastructure/windows-server/main.tf: Error reading
>   config for aws_instance[worker]: aws_iam_role.windows_server_role:
>   resource variables must be three parts: TYPE.NAME.ATTR in:

here is the relevant code

```
resource "aws_instance" "worker" {
  ami                  = "${data.aws_ami.windows_server.image_id}"
  instance_type        = "${var.instance}"
  iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_role.windows_server_role}"  // <- ERROR here
  get_password_data    = "true"
```

I reckon to fix it I can either use

```
iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_role.windows_server_role.id}"
```

or

```
iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_role.windows_server_role.arn}"
```

however it is not obvious in the documentation.

How can I find it out other than hitting an error in run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed on terraform documentation could be better. I do find that you need to reference `aws_iam_instance_profile` rather than `aws_iam_role`. Here is link to doc - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_instance_profile.html .

Code would look something like

```
resource "aws_instance" "worker" {
  ami                  = "${data.aws_ami.windows_server.image_id}"
  instance_type        = "${var.instance}"
  iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.windows_server.name}"
  get_password_data    = "true"
....
}
```

Copying instance profile def from the link shared above:

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "windows_server" {
  name = "windows_server_instance_profile"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.windows_server.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "windows_server" {
  name = "windows_server_role"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Principal": {
               "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I have no idea aws_iam_instance_profile exists. A quick question: does aws explain why they need this extra layer of abstraction? i.e. why not use the aws_iam_role directly in the ec2 instance?